# How to run one line Python command in terminal?

Tags: python, bash, terminal, uuid

I want to get result of a Python function in terminal.

I tried to run the command:

```
$ python3 -m uuid uuid.uuid4().hex
```

And I expect to see the output be something like: `'78cbf0fadaa34ff7ac3f7b965965e207'`

Unfortunately I get error:

> ```
> -bash: syntax error near unexpected token `('
> ```

Answer (score 14):

You were close.

- The flag to run a single command is `-c` and not `-m`.
- You also need to `import uuid` so you can use it.
- You also need to use `print()` to actually see some output.
- Finally the whole passed command has to be in quotes.

```
$ python3 -c "import uuid; print(uuid.uuid4().hex)"
8e79508445db4aca91bb0990529fdd89
```